# How to update BLOB values (MySQL file) with a script?

Tags: mysql, shell, sed, blob

I have an SQL file that contains some BLOB values in some columns.

Using *sed*, I tried to find and replace all values that contain "https://example.com" to "localhost:8888/example" but it doesn't seem to work.

```
sed -i '.bak' 's/https:\/\/example\.com/localhost:8888\/example/g' db_file.sql
```

any ideas on how to update values in a "BLOB" ?

For example, I have in one of the columns a blob that, when read as text, is the following :

```
s:20:"https://example.com";
```

to be transformed into :

```
s:20:"localhost:8888/example";
```

Comment: You must include a minimal example of what you're trying that's not working.

Comment: Please include an example line of `db_file.sql`

Answer (score 1):

That looks like php serialized data, the `s` means its a string and the 20 is the length of the string, so you'll have to change the length as well with the replace.
So the replacement would be something like

```
s:22:"localhost:8888/example";
```